# How to align 6 cameras fast, 2 on each axis facing each other?

Tags: camera

Imagine 6 cameras, 2 on each coordinate axis facing each other. This is what I try to achieve.

However when I first added 6 cameras, chose the first, clicked onto numpad <kbd>1</kbd> to get into frontview and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>, this camera indeed aligned well, but when I chose the second camera and tried to position it somewhere else by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> , the first camera got aligned again, not the second how I expected.

Comment: You must make the second camera the active camera and then align it to the view.

Comment: thanks, could someone post an answer how to make the camera active, i am searching in the panel but can t find the keyword "active"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make the second camera the active camera and then align it to the view.

You can make a selected camera the active camera by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

You can also access this functionality from the 3D view header *View* menu.

> View -> Cameras -> Set Active Object as Camera